# Row label group range as percentage, not decimal

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, pivot-table

I have an excel 2013 pivot table that looks like this:

[image: pivot table]

When i am grouping the rows, % changes to decimal:

[image: % changes to decimal when grouped]

Is there a way to express groups' ranges in % ?

Regards,

Comment: Quick answer - you can overwrite the labels yourself manually: `75-80%` etc. Just click on a label and type over the top of it.

Comment: Thank you Andi, but it is not practical when there are 10+ similar tables to maintain, with ranges being fine-tuned as the database expands. Any efficient way?

Comment: Two ways spring to mind: 1) a macro that iterates through the list in the pivot table and overwrites the labels, or 2) add a column to your raw data that does the percentage banding for you - and use that column in your pivot table labels instead.

Comment: or option 3) insert a column to the left of your pivot table containing formulas that look at your labels, and converts them into a human-friendly label - then hide the column containing ugly labels so you only see the nice ones.